# UILabel で表示したテキストの一部分だけ色を変える方法 ( Swift )

Tags: swift, xcode, uilabel

`UILabel` を設置し、テキストの一部分だけを赤文字に変えたいのですが、

```swift
import UIKit
    class ViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }

        //UILabelのOutlet
        @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

    }
```

基本的に Storyboard での操作のため、コードは紐付け部分しかないのですが、 `UIButton` を押したときに次の文章に行くような動作を書く予定です。

Storyboard 内でラベルを色別に複数に分けるという方法も試したのですが、とても面倒で `ViewController` が見にくく、複雑になってしまいます。どうコーディングしていけば、より少ない行数で、なおかつ簡単に一部分だけ色を変えることが出来るでしょうか？

お詳しい方がいましたらご回答宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

属性付きテキスト（[`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html)）を用いて文字の一部の色を変えることができます。

`Storyboard`上で設定すればコーディング不要です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます！参考になりました。

Answer (score 3):

`NSMutableAttributedString`を作成して`UILabel`の`attributedText`に設定すればよいです。

```
let attrText= NSMutableAttributedString(string: "aaa bbb ccc")
attrText.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                           value: UIColor.redColor(),
                           range: NSMakeRange(4, 3))
myLabel.attributedText = attrText
```

Comment: ご回答有り難うございます！参考になりました。